# how to evaluate to multivariable function

Tags: matlab

Consider the function `f(y1,y2,y3,y4,z1)=(-(z1^3)/(y3^2))(3(y2-y1+y3^(-1)-z1/10)^2+(1/5)(y2-y1+y3^(-1)-(z1)/10))-y4` with 5 variables. When I put `f(1,1,1,1,1)` I find the answer but when I write `f(v)` in which `v=(1,1,1,1,1)` matlab does not work. How can I do that (by the second way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper function, that will take a vector as input argument and 'unpacks' this vector before calling your function.

```
f(y1,y2,y3,y4,z1) = (-(z1^3)/ ...;               % your function
fv(v) = f(v(1),v(2),v(3),v(4),v(5));
```

Or alternatively, make f refer to elements in the input vector by using the appropriate indices:

```
f(v) = (-(v(5)^3)/(v(3)^2)); ... % etc.
```